# What part(s) of this recursive function are truncating the value of my input string?

Tags: javascript

As I continue my quest to master recursions, I come across this problem.
String "s" is obviously chipped away at the head and the tail until it's length <= "1", but I don't see where in the function this chipping away occurs.

Help?

```
function isPalindrome(s)
{
    if (s.length <= 1) return true;
    console.log(s);
    return s[0] == s[s.length -1]  &&  isPalindrome(s.substr(1,s.length -2));    
}

isPalindrome("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba");
```

Comment: The part where there's a substring operation?

Comment: A question that may help enlighten you:  How many times is `isPalindrome` called?  What is it called with the first time?  What is it called with the second time? And so on…  `s` isn't "chipped away" so much as that each call to `isPalindrome` is called multiple times, and each call is with a different string, and though within the body of the function, the string is called `s`, `s` is different to each call.

Comment: Obviously it is not length equals 1, it is length equals 0 or 1. 'abba' is a palindrome, but what are the steps of recursion?

Comment: Enlightenment! I think... I must ponder it a few minutes.

Comment: OK. The "s is different to each call" is the key. Thanks sirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function isPalindrome(s)
{
    // if this is a 0 or 1 character string it is a palindrome 
    if (s.length <= 1) return true;
    console.log(s);

    // if the first character is last character and the substring
    // from second character to second last character is also palindrome,
    // return true, else return false.
    return s[0] == s[s.length -1]  &&  isPalindrome(s.substr(1,s.length -2));    
}

isPalindrome("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba");
```

The chipping part is of course `s.substr(1,s.length -2)` = substring.

Answer (score 2):

`s.substr` is what does the cut.

it passes susbtring of the string from the second character to the one before last.

Answer (score 1):

```
s.substr(1,s.length -2)
```

The function substr returns a string between the two values passed in.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Answer (score 1):

It happens in this statement:

```
isPalindrome(s.substr(1,s.length -2)
```

You are recursing on a substring of your string, in which it chops off the last character.

Answer (score 0):

Why such a difficult function to detect a palindrome?

```
function isPalindrome(s)
{
    return s.split("").reverse().join("") == s;   
}
```

This would be much easier.

Comment: That would not teach me recursions. It's a learning exercise only.

Comment: @dwilbank Oh ok sorry